# Why $f(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n\ln(n)}$ $\in c^n$

Tags: calculus, power-series, uniform-convergence

consider $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n\ln(n)}$ and $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{1+n^4}$.

why $f(x)\in c^n$ in $[\frac{-1}{8},\frac{1}{9}]$ and $h(x)\in c^2$ in $\mathbb{R}$

I think h(x) is a periodic function and I think it can get derivative infinte times.

I just not sure I understand how to show that a function of series can get derivative specific times.

Comment: By $c^n$ do you mean differentiable $n$ times with $f^{(n)}$ continuous? ($\mathscr{C}^n$ or $\textbf{C}^n$ are better notations).

Comment: I mean that you can derivative it $n$ times, my bad for notation, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$f(x)$ is the sum of a power series whose radius of convergence is
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{n\ln(n)}=1$$
thus $ f $ is $C^\infty $ at $(-1,1)$ and therefore at $ [-\frac 18 \frac 19] $.

$h $ is the sum of a series of functions satisfying

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\;|\frac{\sin(nx)}{2+n^4}|\le \frac{1}{n^4}$$
thus the series is uniformly convergent at $\Bbb R$.
The series of the derivatives satisfies
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R)\;\; |\frac{n\cos(nx)}{1+n^4}|\le \frac{1}{n^3}$$

thus, $h$ is differentiable at $\Bbb R$ and
$$h'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\cos(nx)}{1+n^4}$$
but

$$|\frac{-n^2\sin(nx)}{1+n^4}|\le \frac{1}{n^2}$$

thus
$h'$ is differentiable at $\Bbb R$ and
$$h''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-n^2\sin(nx)}{1+n^4}$$

so, $ h''$ is continuous at $ \Bbb R$.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly $h(x)$ is $C^\infty$? in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Sagigever No, i didn't say that.

Comment: So, I am not sure I understood why $h(x) \in C^2$

Comment: @Sagigever Yes, $h$ is just $C^2$ at R.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand, thank you for your help

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Nice solution! (+1) Just forgot to confirm there is pointwise convergence at an $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, which is obvious in this case, but still important to check. Although, how do you prove that $h'''$ isn't continuous?

Comment: @Bcpicao $h''$ is continuous.

Comment: @Bcpicao No, i did not. I said, it is a great hint.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Do you know how to prove it?